# Position DataGridViewComboBoxColumn's position

Tags: c#

I would like to ask, how do I specifically place a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`'s to a specific column? Currently the generated `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` is positioned on the last column.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cmb.HeaderText = "Select Data";
cmb.Name = "cmb";
cmb.
//cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 4;
for (listItem = 0; listItem < dtLstItem.Rows.Count; listItem++)
{
    cmb.Items.Add(dtLstItem.Rows[listItem][1]);
}
dtgPo.Columns.Add(cmb);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DisplayIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

> Gets or sets the display order of the column relative to the currently
>   displayed columns.

```
cmb.DisplayIndex = 0; //first column
```